# How To Invoke Setter Method using Reflection API But does not mention anything like FieldName & MethodName

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

How To Invoke setter Method using Reflection API. but the Problem is that we don't specify the Field Name , Method Name like

```
Method method = User.class.getDeclaredMethod("setName", String.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(user, "Some name");
```

And Also This

```
TestClass igsm = new TestClass();
      User user = new User();   

    Method methodName= igsm.getMethod("name",user.getClass(),"setter");
    methodName.setAccessible(true);
    igsm.invokeSetter(user,"Sanket",methodName);
```

In That cases we just specify the  Method Name , Field Name then we set the value bases of Method Name , Field Name.

I want does not specify anything. And check on the base of value which setter method is called.I can not hard code anything in the program. and extract all the information on runtime and set the value in the appropriate method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not specifying anything'? You need to tell reflection what method you want to invoke.

Comment: But Only specifying the Method name We don't specify the Parameter Type and Filed Name Its possible to invoke the setter only bases of Method Name

Comment: We don't extract anything in reflection

Comment: What do you mean by 'bases'? You mean methods that don't take any arguments?

Comment: Spring invokes the setter which knows how to set a field and which field to set.

Comment: If you are invoking a setter method, it will need one extra argument, the value to set... no idea what the OP really wants to do

Comment: I mean we only pass MethodName and invoke the  setter. we  not specify the argument type of setter method

Comment: @sanketjaiswal If it is a *setter* it means you need to pass a value to it. It is setter, so setting an internal field to some value that it is expecting as an argument.

Comment: I agree with you in this case i also need value argument

Comment: What can i do in this situation

Comment: I only want I can specify the Method Name then method will invoke and set the value in invoked setter method you understand @JBX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way we can easily invoke the private setter Method by Reflection. I have only specify the value then it will identify which setter method to invoke.

```
//MainMethod

    public static class InvokeMain 
        {
            public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable 
            {
                Object obj1 = getBean("www.Fouth.User");

                System.out.println(obj1.toString());
            }

        }

    //Customize Method


      public static void extractMethod(Method[] method,Object valueObj,Object classObj) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
        {
            for(Method m:method)
            {   
                Type[] pType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();

                for(int i=0;i<pType.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("The pType[]"+pType[i]);         

                    if(valueObj.getClass().equals(pType[i]))
                    {   
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        m.invoke(classObj,valueObj.getClass().toString().valueOf(valueObj));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

      //ReflectionMethod


    public static Object getBean(String beanClassName) throws Exception
        {
            Class klass = Class.forName(beanClassName);
            Object obj = klass.newInstance();               
            Method[] b = klass.getDeclaredMethods();

            RefLevel3.extractMethod(b,"sanket",obj);
            RefLevel3.extractMethod(b,23,obj);


            return obj;
        }
```